# Double filter to find the position of a particular cell in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a data set like this

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Case Number
    </th>
    <th>Case Status
    </th>
    <th>Last amended time
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111122
    </td>
    <td>new
    </td>
    <td>10/12/2018 10:54
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111122
    </td>
    <td>open
    </td>
    <td>10/12/2018 10:54
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>111122
    </td>
    <td>pending
    </td>
    <td>10/12/2018 10:55
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>111122
    </td>
    <td>solved
    </td>
    <td>10/12/2018 11:05
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>111122
    </td>
    <td>re-opened
    </td>
    <td>11/12/2018 10:00
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111123
    </td>
    <td>new
    </td>
    <td>10/1/2019 10:54
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111123
    </td>
    <td>open
    </td>
    <td>10/1/2019 10:56
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>111123
    </td>
    <td>new
    </td>
    <td>10/1/2019 10:56
    </td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>111123
    </td>
    <td>open
    </td>
    <td>10/1/2019 10:57
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111126
    </td>
    <td>new
    </td>
    <td>21/1/2019 10:54
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>111126
    </td>
    <td>open
    </td>
    <td>21/1/2019 10:54
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>111126
    </td>
    <td>on-hold
    </td>
    <td>21/1/2019 10:57
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>111126
    </td>
    <td>solved
    </td>
    <td>23/1/2019 09:23
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>111126
    </td>
    <td>closed
    </td>
    <td>30/1/2019 10:54
    </td>
  </tr>




</table>
```

so this is the table since i cannot paste a table here. just run it with any html editor you can see my table

or it's basically a bunch of data like this.

case_number    status    time
111122         new       10/12/2018 10:54
111122         open      10/12/2018 10:54
111122         pending   etc...

basically each row contains three values. 
so basically for each individual case number i want to find the beginning "new" time, the difference between the first "new" time and "open" time, and the time difference between the very first "new" time and the very last "solved" time.

i know how to get the individual case number by removing duplicates. but from here how do i proceed?

Thanks so so much!
btw I can only work on this with excel.

Comment: This stinks of `Sales Force` export. If correct, I feel your pain

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is sorted. i can think of the below solution to your problem right now.
Paste all your Unique entries of case IDs in Column F and use below formula in cell G2 and paste it till last entry.

Below formula is written considering your Case IDs of raw data in Column A, Status in B and Time in column C. And Column F has unique entries of Case IDs.

=INDEX(C:C,COUNTIF(A:A,F2)+MATCH(F2,A:A,0)-1,1)-INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,0),1)